# Can I rename a dataset in the VS 2005 properties window and have this refactor through my code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, refactoring, dataset, rename

I tried the above but when I attempted to rebuild I received errors as the compiler couldn't find the dataset by it's old name.

I know it might be lazy, but I'm used to being able to rename an item in it's properties window and have the refactoring happen silently behind the scenes for me. Is there a way I can do the same thing with a dataset or should I use the find and replace function (along with a fair bit of double checking). My project isn't especailly big so find-replace-check won't take to long but I might need to do it on bigger projects in future

G

**EDIT:** Attempting the below solution gives the following error
    The file 'DataSet.cs' could not be refactored. The current object is auto-generated and only supports renaming through the DataSet Designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that the VS2005 refactoring rename that's built in would handle this. Right-click an instance the object name in the code editor and select rename.

You can look here for further info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379618.aspx#vs05_refac_topic8